# Server disk encrpytion prevents connection after SSH remote reboot

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, encryption, remote-desktop

newbie here. I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS on an old machine for a home server project using a static IP address. Running OpenSSH server on it enables me to connect remotely from my Windows7 laptop through Putty client. Works great except for a big obstacle. When I installed the server's operating system I choose logical volume management with encryption. If I need to reboot the server remotely due to some changes it of course prompts for a passphrase to unlock the disk. During this time it is impossible to remotely connect via SSH (I assume because the SSH server isn't started yet and things are encrypted). How do I get around this? I can't be the only one that has this problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible right now.  Some people have got it to work and others can't get it to work.

It's because of this bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/595648